# Aligning a series of divs

Tags: html, css

I'm working on building I website and I'm having some difficulty. This is how it currently looks:

http://i1134.photobucket.com/albums/m618/eshellborn/ScreenShot2012-11-28at43250PM.png

And, of course this is how I want it to look:

http://i1134.photobucket.com/albums/m618/eshellborn/ScreenShot2012-11-28at43306PM.png

I've tried so many div align this and stuff like that and nothing seems to be working. Any ideas? Code below:

HTML:

```
<div class="realtor"> 
    <img src="bronson.png" align="left" />
    <div class="innerrealtor">
        <h3>Bronson Carmichael</h3>
        <p class="realtorinfo"> Bronson has been in the industry for thousands of years, with over 12 client expiriences. Join him on your journey to find a home in the Cranbrook area. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="viewlistings">
        <div>View Bronson's Listings</div>
        <img src="viewarrow.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.innerrealtor {
    width: 450px;
    margin-left: 90px;
    margin-top: -3px;
}
.realtor {
    padding: 15px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    background-color: #F9F8E7;
    width: 750px;
    height: 70px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.viewlistings {
    width: 180px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #018D0E;
    border-radius: 4px;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}
.viewlistings div {
    padding-top: 3px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    font-family: 'Sanchez', serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 100;
}
.viewlistings img {
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I edited your CSS and it's working now:

give `.viewlistings div` your preferred `width` and `margin-right`

```
.innerrealtor {
width: 450px;
margin-left: 90px;
margin-top: -3px;
float:left;
}


.realtor {
padding: 15px;
margin-top: 25px;
background-color: #F9F8E7;
width: 750px;
height: 70px;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.viewlistings {
width: 180px;
height: 50px;
background-color: #018D0E;
border-radius: 4px;
float: right;
text-align: right;
}

.viewlistings div {
padding-top: 3px;
margin-right: 0px;
font-family: 'Sanchez', serif;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 100;
width:100px;
background:red;
float:left;
}

.viewlistings img {
position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get `.viewlistings` into place by moving its markup before `.innerrealator`.  Only then will it float into the right place.  Also, if you remove `height: 70px;` from `.realtor`, then that box will expand to contain its children.

I can't see your images, but you'll probably need to do the same thing to `viewarrow.png`.

Comment: Wow, that was easy. Still isn't perfect but makes it a lot better. I'll fiddle with it a bit more a little later, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this, I've tried to re-create your situation:

```
jsFiddle:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6rCgc/

I think I've achieved what you are trying using a little simpler markup and css.

Comment: Just quickly, I'm doing this for work and I'm not going to work again until next week, but I really appreciate it. I'll take a look at it a bit more then.